# How to use Fabric Joomla form dropdown plugin with multiple selections under MySQL

Tags: mysql, plugins, joomla, dropdown

I am using Fabric 3.5.2 under Joomla 3.7.0. I have a problem with interpreting MySQL fields saved with a dropdown plugin with multiple selections enabled. Say, I have a field name "someField" with multiple selections in a form: "option1", "option2", "option3". When saved and inserted into MySQL database, it has a form of: "["option1", "option2", "option3"]" (in brackets as given). I need to iterate over all "options" and use them in PHP code. I could replace "[" and "]" with empty string "" and convert the string into sub-strings. But I wonder if there is a simpler solution or if - I am missing something - this field value is ready to be used as an array.
So far I used

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

where

```
$result = mysqli_query($handle, $sql)
```

and then

```
$row["$product1"]
```

where

```
$product1
```

is just a field name variable.
The question is how to get array of the field under multiple selections of dropdown.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, do not expect the community to do all the work alone. Maybe some code/data examples would be helpful.

Comment: I revised the question, thanks to @friedemann_bach.